# ignore header when checking for duplicates

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to ignore the header when checking for duplicates. I am using a code to check the same column on two different worksheets and it picks up the header as a duplicate. If I have it start on row 2 it skips copying over the duplicate and only copies the third one and down.

```
lR1 = S1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lR2 = S2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each c In S1.Range("A1", "A" & lR1)
    If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
        n = 0
        On Error Resume Next
        n = Application.Match(c.Value, S2.Range("A1", "A" & lR2), 0)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If n > 0 Then
            If Not dRws Is Nothing Then
                c.EntireRow.Select
                Selection.Cut
                Sheets("Duplicate").Select
                Range("a2").Select
                Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                S1.Select
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered it myself :D I had a line farther down that deleted anything stored as dRws, since I already moved the rows to another sheet, there was no use for it.